# ACF Relationship + WP Template Parts

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, get-template-part

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated - I've been grappling with it for days :)

I have 2 post types - `product` + `offer`

I have an ACF relationship field `related_products`.

This field returns an array of post IDs `Array ( [0] => 395 [1] => 120 [2] => 388 [3] => 391 )`

I am using `related_products` on the `offer` post type - it's a one-way relationship (not bi-directional).

Each of my post types has a "card" template part that I use in all my loops - that's what I want to do here ... use the `related_products` IDs to get the `product` card parts and show them on the `offer`.

I had no luck with the ACF documentation - but that's probably because I'm a noob.

- https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/
- https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-relationship-query/

Instead, I set up a custom `WP_Query` that get's me close, but not there.

The `if ( $custom_query->have_posts() )` IS working - when an `offer` has related products, the correct product cards ARE displayed.

But, when an `offer` has no `related_products`, ALL products are being shown.

My questions are:

- Is a custom `WP_QUERY` the right/best way to go about this?
- If so, what do I need to fix in the query?

Thank you for your time and help :)

```
// Array ( [0] => 395 [1] => 120 [2] => 388 [3] => 391 )
$related_products = get_field('related_products');

$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post__in' => $related_products,    
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'cache_results'  => false,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false, 
    'update_post_term_cache' => false, 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'paged' => false,
);

$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :  
    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : 
        $custom_query->the_post(); 
        get_template_part( 'parts/card', get_post_type() );
    endwhile;
else : 
    // do something else
endif; 
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My OP is about using the ACF relationship field in `WP_QUERY`. The ACF documentation leaves out one helpful bit that @JacobPeattie supplied.

My final working code looks like this:

```
// ACF field is set to return IDs.
// Array ( [0] => 395 [1] => 120 [2] => 388 [3] => 391 )

$related_product = get_field( 'related_product' );

if ( $related_product ) :

    global $post; // missing from ACF documentation

    foreach ( $related_product as $post ) : // Must be called $post. 
        setup_postdata( $post ); 
        get_template_part( 'parts/card', get_post_type() );
    endforeach;

    wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
```

However, part of Jacob's explanation and subsequent comments are wrong. Because I rely on this community for accurate information, I can't accept his answer as correct.

Jacob incorrectly asserts that passing an array of IDs to `WP_QUERY` and then using the `fields` parameter to return only IDs is redundant and won't work.

You can use any number of things to inform `WP_QUERY` which posts to GET - terms, post type, IDs. This is completely separate from what you tell the query to RETURN - there is nothing redundant about passing then returning IDs.

The `fields` parameter defaults to returning all fields. Alternatively, you can set `fields` to return `ids` (note plural).

Deciding to return all fields or just IDs is a matter of optimization - if you don't need all fields, then don't return them.

Here are two examples from my live site demonstrating that YOU DO NOT NEED ALL FIELDS in many common scenarios. You can easily try these for yourself and I've linked to more info below.

This example displays a field - `the_title` ... super common, I use it all the time and you don't need to return all fields to do it.

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'fields' => 'ids',
);

$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :  

    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : 
        $custom_query->the_post(); 
        the_title();
    endwhile;

else : 
    // do something else
endif; 

wp_reset_query();
```

Here's an even more complex / optimized example. This one is for displaying a template part. This part has standard stuff like `the_title` + ACF fields + an Add Favorite feature + pulls in other parts. The results are filterable by FacetWP.

Again, you only need `WP_QUERY` to return IDs.

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'cache_results'  => false,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false, 
    'update_post_term_cache' => false, 
    'facetwp' => true, 
);

$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : 

    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : 
        $custom_query->the_post(); 
        get_template_part( 'parts/card', get_post_type() );                           
    endwhile;

else :
    // do something else
endif;

wp_reset_query();
```

You can read more about optimizing `WP_QUERY` here (and lots of other places):

- https://kinsta.com/blog/wp-query/

Thinking about it, these examples make perfect sense - things like `global Spost` and `setup_postdata($post)` and `$custom_query->the_post()` are specifically for setting context and ensuring the correct ID is referenced so you can then get the right field, template etc ...

And why would a database need anything more than an ID to get a record's associated fields? ... The only answer I can think of is if the database is poorly designed ... In fact, I have never had a scenario where returning just IDs hasn't worked.

I'm not claiming to be an expert - I only know that you can return just IDs because I read about it, tried it in my own projects, and it works.

Comment: Not to bring this up again as it seems to have been hit in previous comments but Jacob is correct. The method `$query->the_post()` calls [`$query->setup_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/setup_postdata/) and the first line is a conditional which says if what is given is **not** a WP_Post, call the database and get that post. By only requesting Post IDs you are not giving `setup_postdata()` a WP_Post but a Post ID which it then needs to get the rest of the post. While your code does work, in this case it is calling the database more times than it needs to.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your explanation and understand - I wish Jacob had said it isn't optimal instead of insisting it doesn't work ... It does work and is right for some scenarios, just not mine.

Answer (score 3):

> But, when an offer has no related_products, ALL products are being
>   shown.

This is because you're not doing anything to check if the field has a value before running your query. If this is empty:

```
$related_products = get_field('related_products');
```

Then that makes the query argument equivalent to:

```
'post__in' => [],
```

And if that argument value is empty, it doesn't query no posts, it just gets ignored, which means you're query is the equivalent of:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type'              => 'product',
    'fields'                 => 'ids',
    'cache_results'          => false,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false, 
    'update_post_term_cache' => false, 
    'posts_per_page'         => -1, 
    'paged'                  => false,
);
```

Which is querying *all* products.

So you need to check if your field has any values before doing anything, then only querying if there are any.

Your other problem is that you have `fields` set to `ids`. If you do this then the result is just an array of posts IDs, which you already have because that's what you're querying. If you want to use the loop with your results, you need to remove that line. So all you should have is:

```
$related_products = get_field( 'related_products' );

if ( $related_products ) {
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post__in'  => $related_products,    
    );

    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :  
        while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : 
            $custom_query->the_post(); 
            get_template_part( 'parts/card', get_post_type() );
        endwhile;
    else : 
    // do something else
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

But doing this query at all is unnecessary. If you set the field to return post objects, rather than IDs, you can just loop through those:

```
$related_products = get_field( 'related_products' );

if ( $related_products ) {
    global $post; // Necessary.

    foreach ( $related_products as $post ) : // Must be called $post. 
        setup_postdata( $post ); 
        get_template_part( 'parts/card', get_post_type() );
    endforeach;

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

This is the same as [Faye's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/342692/39152), I'm just including it for completeness. If you're receiving any errors from that, then the issue is somewhere else. Probably inside your card template.

Comment: Thank you Jacob! Very good answer. I agree, I would expect the issue to be coming from elsewhere.

Comment: First I want to say thanks to you both for the help - time is valuable and I so totally appreciate it <3 

Second - @JacobPeattie answer is NOT the same as @Faye - Adding `global $post` solved my issue - Yay!

Again - Thank you both for your time and help - this is such a great community!

Comment: Not because I need it here, but because I'm still learning ... I'm not sure this part of Jacobs answer is accurate ...
"Your other problem is that you have fields set to ids ... If you want to use the loop with your results, you need to remove that line" ...

It seems passing an array of IDs to `$args` is separate from aksing `WP_QUERY` to return just IDs ...  without `'fields' => 'ids'` the query is going to return all fields by default. That's a perfomance issue - why waste resources getting fields I don't need? ... https://kinsta.com/blog/wp-query/#returned-fields

Comment: Firstly, returning IDs from the query is totally redundant, because _you already have the IDs_!  So even if you did only want the IDs there’s no point querying for IDs you already have. Secondly, you _do_ need those fields. Where do you think the content you’re going to output comes from? If you use `the_title()` then you need to get the titles of the post from the database.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you are totally wrong about this ... the official documentation states that without this parameter, ALL fields are returned ... THAT is redundant when all you need are IDs to get template parts ... you DO need all fields if you want to get a single field like `the_title` .... have a look at the  link I provided above and here ... https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#return-fields-parameter

Comment: You're very much misguided on this. Those template parts need to use the details from the post, which means they need to be queried. `setup_postdata()` and `the_post()` require the full details for those functions to work.

Comment: @acobPeattie  - for the sake of anyone stumbling across this, I have to push back and say you're the one who is misguided ... If you look at my OP, I have both the ACF field and `WP_Query` set to IDs and am displaying template parts just fine - my problem was about all products showing, not about getting the parts to display.

Comment: I have thoroughly researched this ... You can use IDs, terms, and post types to tell `WP_QUERY` which posts to GET ... You can use the `return_fields` parameter to RETURN all fields or just IDs ... If using `WP_QUERY` to display a template part, you only need to return IDs, as vaguely explained in the Codex, and better explained by numerous authorities ... In this scenario, returning all fields is a redundant waste of resources ... GET and RETURN are 2 different things.

Comment: Now you're just misinforming people. If you set `WP_Query` it to only return IDs, then when you run `the_post()`, or `setup_postdata()`, _which is the part that makes the template parts work_, then WordPress is forced to query the database for the full post anyway, only now it's doing it in dozens of queries instead of one. What you're doing is considerably less efficient. That's all putting aside the fact that the code in your question is completely redundant because _you're querying the database for a list of IDs that you already have!_.

Comment: When you display posts WordPress has to query the post data at some point. By only returning IDs from your query you're just deferring this query to a later, but less efficient stage. There's no reason you shouldn't just query all the posts you need up front.

Comment: Again, only responding because I rely on this community for accurate information ... I sincerely appreciate that you helped me get the official ACF method to work, but part of your explanation is wrong ... I've provided links that explain it and I have 2 live sites that demonstrate it ... You could easily prove it to yourself in one of your own themes ... You can either accept facts and update your answer, or I can un-mark it as correct and answer the question myself ... no skin off my back either way.

Comment: It's not wrong, you just lack sufficient understanding of the WordPress code to know why your code is working. If you want me to explain it to you, post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, but it looks like you're trying to do something much simpler than what you've got going there. I use the method [shown here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) on a regular basis and it works just fine.

```
<?php 

$posts = get_field('related_products');

if( $posts ): ?>

    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'parts/card', get_post_type() );?> 
        <!-- this is the only thing I'm not sure if you'd want to just directly call 'parts/card', 'product' -->

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I stated in my OP, I tried the methods in the ACF documentation as you describe ... I tested setting the field to return both the post object and the post ID ... This method works great for getting specific fields, like post title, but doesn't work for getting template parts ... with either the object or the ID I get this warning: "Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /www/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 3323"

Comment: ... and that error is in rewind_posts() ... but I don't know enough to tell you what that means :P